# Ubuntu ARP reply configuration

Tags: ubuntu, networking, arp

I am wondering what/if there is any configuration that enables arp replies.

I have an Ubuntu machine with two interfaces - one is ethernet to a non-public LAN, the other is Wifi which connects to the public internet. I need internet access on the private LAN for one computer temporarily, so I set an SNAT so that the address on the private LAN is mapped to the WiFi network LAN.

EDIT: I failed to mention that I also have a DNAT set to translate the address back.

Sending a ping outbounds to 8.8.8.8 hits, but on return my WiFi router doesn't know "who has" this natted address (192.168.7.33) so it sends an arp request.

I ran `sudo arp -v -i wlp1s0 -s 192.168.7.33 84:7b:eb:35:a4:e0`, where the hw addr is the hw addr associated with the ethernet link(I also ran the same command followed by 'pub' and it still didn't send). Here it is now in my arp table...:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask        Iface
192.168.7.33             ether   84:7b:eb:35:a4:e0   CM                    wlp1s0
```

However, the Ubuntu box still never replies to arps -

```
   19:26:59.542278 IP 192.168.7.33 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: 19:27:51.477054 IP 192.168.7.33 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 3312, seq 2692, length 64
19:27:51.493773 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.7.33 tell 192.168.7.254, length 46
```

The first message is the ping on the way to google, the second is the router looking for 192.168.7.33.

Referencing this post,
[Linux does not reply to ARP request messages if requested IP address is associated with another (disabled) interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205708/linux-does-not-reply-to-arp-request-messages-if-requested-ip-address-is-associat), I checked my kernel's Ip routing tables:

```
sudo ip route show table local
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.3.0 dev enp0s31f6  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.12 
local 192.168.3.12 dev enp0s31f6  proto kernel  scope host  src 192.168.3.12 
broadcast 192.168.3.255 dev enp0s31f6  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.12 
broadcast 192.168.7.0 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.7.117 
local 192.168.7.117 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope host  src 192.168.7.117 
broadcast 192.168.7.255 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.7.117
```

In this question, the user had a route set for reaching the address(unlike my NAT), so I went ahead and added a route as well, and it still did not ARP:

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.7.254   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp1s0
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
192.168.7.33    192.168.3.10    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s31f6
```

Is there a setting on Ubuntu that I can change so that my machine will reply to ARP requests? If not, where is the next place to look to see why we're not responding?

EDIT 2: Here is how I set up the NAT:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.3.10 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.7.33
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.7.33 -j DNAT --to-dest 192.168.3.10
```

EDIT 3: Changing to masquerading from DNAT/SNAT worked, and is far easier/more scalable.

Comment: The questions is not entirely clear. Does the router had an interface in that network? Is the machine able to ping the router?

Comment: @roaima: Sorry, that's wrong. You don't need corresponding DNAT rules for SNAT rules; the connection tracking does that automatically for you. Try it out if you don't believe me.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The router has an interface on the WiFi LAN, 192.168.7.0/24. The Ubuntu machine can ping the router, and access the internet, etc..

Comment: @roaima I have the corresponding DNAT set as well.

Comment: @dirkt i didn't have a machine handy to check, and TBH i can never remember if the check-in tracking handles an explicit snat/dnat rule out not. If that is the case i apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARP replies are enabled automatically. It might be possible to turn them off with some entries in `/proc` or `/sys`, but I'd have to search for that.

What you have is a pretty standard situation for NAT. You haven't supplied the most important information, namely how you set up NAT, but usually one does it like this:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD 
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
```

This enables forwarding, clears `iptables` rules, sets up a default policy, sets up filtering in the `FORWARD` chain so any packets going from `$INTIF` to `$EXTIF` are accepted, while for the reverse direction they must be tracked by the connection tracker (`nf_conntrack`). Finally all forwarded packets are `MASQUERADED`, which is `SNAT` with the address present on the interface, so even if this address changes, you'll always use the correct one. No extra routes needed. You can restrict forwarding by source address if you need to.

`$INTIF` is the internal interface (your LAN), `$EXTIF` is the external interface (your WLAN). You can make this persistent using whatever flavour of tools your Ubuntu uses (systemd etc.).

This works out of the box, no fiddling needed. The connection tracker will DNAT returning packets to the correct address with no need for an extra rule, forward them back to the LAN, and send out the ARP on the LAN interface, where it should get send out.

I suspect your setup is somehow different, which is why you end up with funny ARPs in the wrong place.

Comment: @roaima: Yes, but it's probably the solution to his problem, as far as I can guess from what he writes. See "XY problem". If you can tell him how to "enable ARP replies", go ahead and write an answer.

Comment: @roaima: I could have asked him how he set up NAT, read through it, and point out the mistakes. To avoid the additional round-trip, I just gave a working example. Note the "no extra routes needed", the "I added a route as well" might contribute to the behaviour he sees.

Comment: @dirkt I updated my answer to show how I have the NAT set up. Correct me if I am wrong, but the only difference between your masquerading scheme and my scheme is that MASQUERADE ing is dynamic. I think you are right, that is a better way to do it, but a static scheme should still work, and ARP replies should still be transmitted

Comment: Try removing the DNAT rule (and the extra route). You can debug this with `tcpdump -ni wlp1s0` to test if the outgoing ping packet has correct source (the router's IP address on wlp1s0). Also verify with `ip addr` you are SNATing the correct address (or do you MASQUERADE), and you don't accidentally have multiple addresses assigned.

Comment: Changing to Masquerade worked :), I sincerely appreciate your help

Comment: Then there was probably an IP address mixup somewhere, in theory it should also work with SNAT.