# Send packet on one interface and receive it on another one for testing purposes

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, interface

I would like to test the DHCP client that I wrote on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS. I would like to do it locally on my laptop i.e. send and receive DHCP packets inside.

Here is what I tried:

- created two dummy interfaces: `dummy0`, `dummy1`
- created bridge for these 2 interfaces: `br0`

The goal is to send DHCP discover from `dummy0` and receive it on `dummy1`, I'm sending DHCP discover on `dummy0`, unfortunately I don't see any packets on `dummy1` interface. If it could be received the next step would be to run DHCP server on `dummy1` to test how my client is doing.

I see DHCP discover in `wireshark` on `dummy0` interface. I see nothing on `dummy1`. Additionally: I see packet on `br0`.

I assume there may be better way to do this, could you please tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Boomerang packets" (sent out from one local interface, received on another local interface) are considered a routing error (loop somewhere out there) and are dropped by the kernel by default.

Also, dummy devices are a pain to work with.

Better approach: Create a network namespace (or two), put a veth pair between the network namespace and the main namespace (or the two network namespaces). No bridge needed. Then test all you want.

Run an `xterm` in each namespace to make your life easier.

Here's a script I use to do that. Modify as you like.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setup network namespace with veth pair, start xterm in it

# nsterm ns0 veth0 10.0.0 yellow 24
#
# tested: yellow, lime, orange, cyan

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

NS=${1:-ns0}
DEV=${2:-veth0}
DEV_A=${DEV}a
DEV_B=${DEV}b
ADDR=${3:-10.0.0}
ADDR_A=${ADDR}.254
ADDR_B=${ADDR}.1
MASK=${5:-24}
COL=${4:-yellow}

# echo ns=$NS dev=$DEV col=$COL mask=$MASK

ip netns add $NS
ip link add $DEV_A type veth peer name $DEV_B netns $NS
ip addr add $ADDR_A/$MASK dev $DEV_A
ip link set ${DEV}a up
ip netns exec $NS ip addr add $ADDR_B/$MASK dev $DEV_B
ip netns exec $NS ip link set ${DEV}b up
ip netns exec $NS ip link set lo up
ip netns exec $NS ip route add default via $ADDR_A dev $DEV_B
ip netns exec $NS su -c "xterm -bg $COL &" your_username
```

Comment: Packet is sent on veth0a and I see it on veth0b! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer (commands) here is easy to understand and follow.
[For veth pair, ping does not recognize interface name and tc qdisc netem does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511783/for-veth-pair-ping-does-not-recognize-interface-name-and-tc-qdisc-netem-does-no)